# npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN AWS Ubuntu - Corporate Firewall

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, docker, npm

Had to move our AWS server from open internet access to behind a firewall. I set up the new server from scratch. I have a script to build and start a docker image. It works great on the original server. However, firewalled server, no luck.

I've tried "npm set strict-ssl false" and "npm install npm -g --ca=null" + "npm config set ca="""

I've read as much documentation I can find. Nothing has worked and I'm now stuck... Here is the output from the firewalled server.

```
$ docker build . -t lab-server

Sending build context to Docker daemon 23.68 MB
Step 1 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 14989a19b2c6
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf64a1065712
Step 3 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 785f66509c34
Step 4 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 621dfc200257
Step 5 : COPY package.json tsconfig.json /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1dc06475df7f
Step 6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 7cf8b7b036d6
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-10-25T23_34_34_267Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Output from the original non-firewalled server.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  24.2 MB
Step 1 : FROM node:latest
 ---> ae884087f2da
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 09c7c4a2471c
Step 3 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 67ed0cc97232
Step 4 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 144e8824e6c1
Step 5 : COPY package.json tsconfig.json /usr/src/app/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2fe8ebeed67d
Step 6 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c69c300495f1
Step 7 : RUN npm install -g typescript ts-node
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7c6c6a52eb39
Step 8 : COPY ./src /usr/src/app/src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 90e5adf015dd
Step 9 : EXPOSE 3001
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0689a44228c
Step 10 : CMD npm start
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 112ff47fc584
Successfully built 112ff47fc584
f84120db5167603fa2df12503b0ac331c65daf325d25c71203ca3bfb99dc0d1a
Server Started
```